# $\gcd$ of polynomials over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have the polynomials $f,g\neq 0 $ over a field $F$. We know also that $\gcd(f,g)=1$ and 
$$
       \det \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{pmatrix}\neq 0.
$$

I need to prove that $\gcd(af+bg,cf+dg) = 1 $ for every $a,b,c,d \in F$.

I really do not know how to start answer the question. Thanks for helpers!

Comment: You mentioned a polynomial $p(x)$ in the beginning of the question, but it doesn't show up anywhere else?

Comment: you are right, edited.

Comment: You don't need to (and *can't*!) prove it for every $a,b,c,d \in F$. You can only prove it for those $a,b,c,d$ satisfying that determinant condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just work through the equations of gcd (bearing in mind that you're working in $f(x)$, hence constants do not matter):

$ \gcd(af+bg, cf+dg) = \gcd(adf+bdg, cbf + bdg) = \gcd( (ad-bc)f, cbf + bdg) = \gcd( f, cbf+bdg) = \gcd(f, bdg) = \gcd(f, g) = 1$

Comment: why gcd(f,cbf+bdg)=gcd(f,g)?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** What if $\gcd(af+bg,cf+dg) \neq 1$?

Well, By using the Unique Factorization Property of the polynomial ring over a field you can find a prime polynomial $p$ such that $p \mid \gcd(af+bg,cf+dg)$.

Does it give you any idea about how you should go ahead with this argument to get a contradiction?

2nd hint:

Well, since $p \mid af+bg$ and $p \mid cf+dg$ we can conclude that $p \mid d(af+bg)-b(cf+dg) \implies p \mid (ad-bc)f$ .

But $p$ is prime, and $ad-bc \neq 0$, therefore $\gcd(p, ad-bc) =1$ since $p$ is assumed to be a monic polynomial. so, you get $p \mid f$. the same reasoning gives you $p \mid g$. That means $p \mid \gcd(f,g)$ which gives you the contradiction.

Comment: but f,g are polynomyals

Comment: @Shlomi: Yes, but fortunately, we still have the unique factorization theorem for polynomials. Let me fix this in my answer. $K[x]$ is a U.F.D for any field $K$, so, you can find such a prime(I mean irreducible) polynomial.

Comment: ok. but how you get a contradition?

Comment: @Shlomi: I edited my post, but I think I have already spoiled it. I'm sorry for that, but I couldn't think of any other ways to give a second hint. Also, keep in mind that when we are dealing with polynomials, we keep working with monic ones.

Comment: @user: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. The G.C.D for two polynomials is defined to be the 'monic' polynomial that satisfies the G.C.D conditions if that helps clarifying things up.

Comment: @user: OK, I get your point. You mean that there is not a default order like the one we have for integers defind for $K[x]$, right? But that order thing is rather a technical issue that can be fixed without invalidating the proof, but yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @User: Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. Even though that it's possible to define an order on $K[x]$ I think. For example, Suppose that we represent a polynomial by $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots)$. We can define something similar to lexicographic order on the coefficients to compare two polynomials in $K[x]$ by considering the difference of their coefficients. That might be an appropriate order for that technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see linear combinations. Linear combinations mean linear algebra. It is *very* often useful to write linear combinations in terms of matrix arithmetic when you can. In this case, we get the very interesting

$$ \left[ \begin{matrix} af + bg \\ cf + dg \end{matrix} \right]
= \left[ \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix}f \\ g \end{matrix} \right] $$

There are a number of ways you can go from here. Here are two things to get you started.

**Exercise**: compare elementary matrices (i.e. elementary row operations) to steps of the Euclidean algorithm.

**Exercise**: What can you *easily* say about the relationship between $\gcd(f,g)$ and $\gcd(af+bg, cf+dg)$? (optional: rephrase it in terms of vectors and matrices, rather than pairs and linear combinations) How can you use the fact that matrix is invertible to go the other direction?